# automate web application under development in qtp

Tags: automation, qtp, hp-uft

We have one web application which is under development. We want to start our automation without application using UFT.

Is there any way that we can start automation without application availability?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without the application available, you basically have to start creating "stubs" for your real automation work.  This basically involves you writing the structure of your automation without any of the code that actually interacts with your app.  You could do this by creating functions that represent your business process.  The following example illustrates accessing an application, opening an order, and verifying the order total.

```
' Define test parameters
url = "http://testapp.com"
userName = "User name here"
password = "Password here"
orderNumber = 12345
orderTotal = 12.99

' Launch application and login
LaunchApplication url
Login userName, password

' Open an existing order
OpenOrder orderNumber

' Verify the total
VerifyOrderTotal orderTotal
```

You would have functions defined like the following.  They don't do anything now, but you'll add that logic later.

```
Public Sub LaunchApplication(ByVal url)
    ' TODO: Open the application
End Sub

Public Sub Login(ByVal userName, ByVal password)
    ' TODO: Login using the credentials provided
End Sub

Public Sub OpenOrder(ByVal orderNumber)
    ' TODO: Open the order specified
End Sub

Public Sub VerifyOrderTotal(ByVal orderTotal)
    ' TODO: Verify total amount due on open order matches the order total
End Sub
```

Even without an application available, this basic business process should be partially known by the testers.  As you build out these tests, you'll create these stub functions that you will later finalize by the code necessary to interact with the application.

This is just one approach you can take.  You basically have to be creative and write as much code as possible without writing the logic that interacts with the application.  The more modular your design, the more you will be able to accomplish before the application is ready.

Answer (score 1):

[HP's Business Process Testing (BPT)](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetPDF.aspx%2F4AA1-2117ENW.pdf) is meant (among other things) to fill this need. In BPT you create logical Business Components (BC) from which a test can be constructed. You can then build tests and implement the BC in parallel (by separate people). BPT requires working with QC in addition to UFT.

If you don't have the additional license for BPT there are two options. One is as mentioned by [@HgCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25027436/3848). The other is if you know what controls the application should have. Create an object repository manually (or via XML) that contains the objects but no description. Then when the application is ready you can populate the description of the test objects in the object repository with the *update from application* functionality.